# Combine two dataframes, one longer on the right, one on the left

Tags: pandas

I have a situation in pandas where I am trying to combine two dataframes.

X is a simple moving average I calculated along a date range using `pandas.rolling_mean(xdf,window=20)`

Y is a dataframe calculated along the same date range, but which stops 5 items earlier than X.

So, what I've got is:

```
X = 2008-01-01 Nan
    ... 20x
    2008-01-30 922.848
    etc.
    2009-12-31 921.213
```

and

```
Y = 2008-01-01 1.23
    ...
    2008-01-30 1.231
    ...
    2009-12-26 1.11
```

and what I need is:

```
XY = 2008-01-30 922 1.231
     ...
     2009-12-26 911.123 1.11
```

So, basically, I need the dataframes aligned, dropping the excess in X at the end and the excess in Y at the beginning.

How do I do this in pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that you `x` should start from 2008-01-30,after that ,you can simply inner join two dataframes:

```
x=pd.DataFrame({"a":['2008-01-30','2008-02-28'],"value_x":[1,2]})
y=pd.DataFrame({"a":['2008-01-01','2008-01-30'],"value_y":[1,2]})
xy=pd.merge(x,y,how="inner",on=["a"])
```